# How to create onserverclick event already created in back-end HTML table and div in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

I have created an HTML table in code behind (ASP- C#) using HTML tags to retrieve data from the database. It works fine. Then I added a new column for edit button and delete button using HTML tags in the same way.

Similarly, I created a div panel to retrieve data from the database(This panel is used to check vehicle availability). Using while loop data retrieve to this div. It also has a button called book now.

Now I want to create an onserverckick event for those buttons. And get the selected id in each row. Because I want to make a reservation according to that selected id.

I have tried several ways but I couldn't find the solution to this problem.

**HTML Table Code**

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Create Database Connection
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= LAPTOP-J70EHC58 ; Initial Catalog= Bus_Management_System ; Integrated Security = True ; Connect Timeout = 30 ; ");
                con.Open();

                //Retrieve package details
                string sqlst = "SELECT * FROM Package ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlst, con);
                
                StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
                //Create Table
                table.Append("<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>");                
                table.Append("<thead>");
                table.Append("<tr>");
                table.Append("<th>Package ID</th>");
                table.Append("<th>Package Name</th>");
                table.Append("<th>Rate Per KM (Rs.) </th>");
                table.Append("<th>Rate Per Additional Day (Rs.) </th>");
                table.Append("<th>Advanced_Per_KM (Rs.) </th>");
                table.Append("<th>Action</th>");
                table.Append("</tr>");
                table.Append("</thead>");

                table.Append("<tbody>");

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        //display package details
                        table.Append("<tr>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[0] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[1] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[2] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[3] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[4] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td><center><button id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-round btn-info btn-xs' runat='server' onserverclick='btnEdit_ServerClick' >Edit</button><button id='btnDelete' class='btn btn-round btn-danger btn-xs' runat='server' >Delete</button></center></td>");
                        table.Append("</tr>");

                    }
                }

                table.Append("</tbody>");
                table.Append("</table>");
                
                pnlTable.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });

                con.Close();

            }
```

**HTML Div Code**

```html
protected void btnCheckAvailability_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create Database Connection
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= LAPTOP-J70EHC58 ; Initial Catalog= Bus_Management_System ; Integrated Security = True ; Connect Timeout = 30 ; ");
                con.Open();

                StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

                //string sqlst3 = " SELECT Route_Name FROM Route WHERE (SELECT Route_ID FROM Bus WHERE Status = 'Available' AND Package_ID = (SELECT Package_ID FROM Package WHERE Package_Name = '" + txtBusPackageName.Value + "')) = Route.Route_ID ";
                //SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sqlst3, con);
                //string routeName = Convert.ToString(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());

                //string sqlst4 = " SELECT First_Name FROM Employee WHERE (SELECT Owner_ID FROM Bus WHERE Status = 'Available' AND Package_ID = (SELECT Package_ID FROM Package WHERE Package_Name = '" + txtBusPackageName.Value + "')) = Employee.Employee_ID AND Employee.Position = 'Owner'  ";
                //SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sqlst4, con);
                //string ownerName = Convert.ToString(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());


                //Retrieve package details
                string sqlst2 = "SELECT * FROM Bus WHERE Status = 'Available' AND Package_ID = (SELECT Package_ID FROM Package WHERE Package_Name = '" + txtBusPackageName.Value + "') ";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlst2, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();


                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                       
                        //display package details
                        table.Append("<div class='col-md-4  profile_details'>");
                        table.Append("<div class='well profile_view'>");
                        table.Append("<div class='col-sm-12'>");
                        table.Append("<h4 class='brief green'><i>" + dr[6] + "</i></h4>");
                        table.Append("<div class='left col-xs-7'>");
                        table.Append("<h2>" + dr[1] + " - " + dr[0] + "</h2>");
                        table.Append("<p><strong>Total Seats: </strong>" + dr[3] + "</p>");
                        table.Append("<ul class='list-unstyled'>");
                        table.Append("<li>Package Name: " + txtBusPackageName.Value + " </li>");
                        table.Append("<li>Bus Type: " + dr[4] + " </li>");
                        table.Append("<li>Bus Owner: " + dr[8] + " </li>");
                        table.Append("</ul>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("<div class='right col-xs-5 text-center'>");
                        table.Append("<img src='images/bus1.jpg' style='width: 106px; height: 112px; ' class='img-circle img-responsive'>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("<div class='col-xs-12 bottom text-center'>");
                        table.Append("<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis'>");
                        table.Append("<p class='ratings'>");
                        table.Append("<a>4.0</a>");
                        table.Append(" <a href=''><span class='fa fa-star'></span></a>");
                        table.Append(" <a href=''><span class='fa fa-star'></span></a>");
                        table.Append(" <a href=''><span class='fa fa-star'></span></a>");
                        table.Append(" <a href=''><span class='fa fa-star'></span></a>");
                        table.Append(" <a href=''><span class='fa fa-star-0'></span></a>");
                        table.Append("</p>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis'>");
                        table.Append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-round pull-right'>Book Now</button>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("</div>");
                        table.Append("</div>");

                    }
                }

                panelBook.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });

                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Response.Write(exception);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The short version is: this is not how asp.net webforms work. You need to add a button control with associated event handler. You can't really do this by appending raw html tags to something. You should really be looking at a databound control like a [repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-cs)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
table.Append("<td><center><button id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-round btn-info btn-xs' runat='server' onserverclick='btnEdit_ServerClick' >Edit</button><button id='btnDelete' class='btn btn-round btn-danger btn-xs' runat='server' >Delete</button></center></td>");
```

You can't add a `runat='server'` control at this point.  The `runat='server'` markup is for ASPX pages, not for the HTML that is being rendered by putting the `table` in a Literal control.  The ASPX parser will never see it.

You could put the HTML up to the button in one Literal.  Then add your buttons, eg.

```
Button btnEdit = new Button();
btnEdit.ClientId = "btnEdit";
btnEdit.CssClass = "btn btn-round btn-info btn-xs";
edibtnEditbutton.Text = "Edit";
btnEdit.Click += btnEdit_ServerClick;

panelBook.Controls.Add(btnEdit);
```

and then add your delete button and then add the rest of the literal.

Comment: shows error in this line - btnEdit.ClientId = "btnEdit"; (In clientID)

Comment: when I run the code it shows this error  - Control 'ctl22' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: @sasanka Is there a form tag? Does it have "runat=server"?

Comment: yes, my package.aspx has a form with "runat=server"..panel is in that form

Comment: @sasanka Can you post your ASPX please.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add your `package_id` inside your `button` on the time of generating your table

```
<button onclick="yourFunction(event, package_id)">Your Button</button>
```

Then  you will get your `id` on every click event of your button

Comment: This is client side only, and will not work for a server side events with asp.net webforms